# I want to create a column of div`s depends to the number of I input in input type=number

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I want to input a number here (ex.5).

```
<div class="container">
        <label style="font-family:agency fb;">How many tracks?</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="num" name="tracks" placeholder="How many tracks?" style="width:15%;font-family:agency fb;font-size:18px;" required>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Go" name="go" style="width:15%;font-family:agency fb;">
    </div>
    <br>
```

Then this division will be 5x.

```
    <div class="container form-inline" name="row">
        <label style="font-family:agency fb;">Track Number</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="tnumber[]" placeholder="Track Number" style="width:5%;font-family:agency fb;font-size:18px;">
        <label style="font-family:agency fb;">Track Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tname[]" placeholder="Track Name" style="width:20%;font-family:agency fb;font-size:18px;">
        <label style="font-family:agency fb;">Track Playtime</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tplaytime[]" placeholder="Track Playtime" style="width:10%;font-family:agency fb;font-size:18px;">
        <label style="font-family:agency fb;">Choose Song</label>
        <input type="file" name="song[]" class="form-control" style="width:20%;" accept="audio/*">
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you use jQuery?

Comment: yes sir i using jquery but not so much can u explain more sir? plss i want to know more. tnx in advance

Comment: Answered for your ref